# How do I access my view from within my view model with Prism?

Tags: prism, prism-7

I'm using Prism for MVVM.  In my main window, I have a ribbon menu, and a tab control which shows all of my views.  I want to be able to dynamically update my ribbon with contextual commands based on which view is currently selected.  The binding is more complicated than just a simple list of commands (each command has an icon, subcommands, different sizes, grouping, etc.), so I think I need to somehow get a reference to my ribbon control within the main view model so I can programatically add/configure my ribbon commands.  How do I get a reference to the view from within the view model?

Comment: What's prism-related about this? To me this looks like a basic wpf question. Which ribbon do you use? The fluent-ribbon is somewhat mvvm-friendly and you can just make the contextual tabs Prism-regions and navigate them to the context whenever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get a reference to the view from within the view model?

Use `i:Interaction.Behaviors` to attach the `Loaded` event of your view to a command on your view model and pass the view as parameter.

And then, get mad while writing the test suites for this. If I were you, I'd do everything else before I force view types into the view model...